# Errors while trying to install packages using tasksel in Debian 9 containers

Tags: debian, terminal, docker, container

I'm running Docker desktop community 2.0.3.
I ran the official nginx and Apache HTTP server containers from docker hub (hub.docker.com).
The container images are based on Debian 9.
Then, I tried to install Debian standard system utilities using tasksel.
I opened a terminal in the container using:

```
docker exec -ti container_id bash
```

I tried to run the tasksel installation

```
# tasksel install standard
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Installing packages
-------------------

..100%
```

The issues are:

- It doesn't open the tasksel TUI (text user interface) as seen in the screenshot.
- I get the errors above and it doesn't finish installation.

Docker desktop is installed on macOS 10.12

[image: Tasksel]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `tasksel`, you need to install `dialog`; in your container:

```
apt update && apt install -y dialog tasksel
```

Then

```
tasksel install standard
```

will work, with the usual interface.

You don’t need to pass the `TERM` variable in.

Many of the standard utilities aren’t much use in a container, however if I were to do this, I would use `aptitude` instead of `tasksel`:

```
apt update && apt install -y aptitude && \
aptitude install -y ~pstandard ~prequired ~pimportant
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out ncurses requires this command:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38774123/3341782
Not sure if there's a better solution.